# How do I get the caret position in textarea from event 'dragover'?

Tags: javascript, html

When selecting text in the *textarea* cursor position and selection, I can get the read properties of *textarea.selectionStart*, *textarea.selectionEnd* and *textarea.selectionDirection* (Figure 1).

If you start dragging the selected text, an additional cursor appears, where the selected fragment will be transferred when the transfer is completed (Figure 2).

How do I get the position of the additional cursor at the 'dragover' event?

[image]